# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a solution with two projects, one in Framework and the other in Core.  They interact with one another.   But I am getting this error in the Framework project even though I have this Nuget Library installed.  I notice that when I delete the older version (System.Configuration) this code will not compile...

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NAME"].ConnectionString;
```

Which tells me that it is ignoring the "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" anyway.  But if I have both installed it errors out at runtime with the above mentioned error. Why would the Framework project even need this library? It's a Core library no?

I should point out that the Framework project is a class library.

Comment: Add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly.  It doesn't come from a nuget library, it's part of the framework

Comment: It's already there.

Comment: I'm not referring to the `using System.Configuration` line.

Comment: It would be useful if you mention the frameworks and packages you compile against and their versions.

Comment: Amy, I know, I have the reference there.

Comment: The Framework project is 4.6.1    The Core project is 2.1

Comment: "They interact with one another." How exactly do they do that? You cannot reference one from the other. Do you mean through IPC, like one has a REST server and the other is a client?

Comment: It's an API.   When the Core endpoint is accessed, It calls a method in the .Net project as part of the functionality.

Comment: Check to see if an older version reference is embedded in the .csproj file (remove it if so and re-add the reference)

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? You cannot reference one from the other. A Core assembly cannot reference a Framework assembly and a Framework assembly cannot reference a Core assembly.

Comment: In the Reference manager of the Core project I have a reference to the other project which allows me to call methods within it.  Both projects are in the same solution.  Core and Framework is project level right? Not Solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference a .NET Framework assembly from a .NET Core assembly (or vice versa).

It might look like it works and it might indeed work for a very small subset of assemblies, but the documentation says you cannot and you will get errors to prove the documentation correct. You just got one of them.

So what is the solution if you want to shared code? Well you could create a .NET Standard assembly. Those can be referenced by *both* .NET Core *and* .NET Framework. But if you need one assembly to be .NET Core and the other to be .NET Framework, you are out of luck. You will have to use indirect means of communication (for example HTTP or named pipes or memory mapped files) as if it were two completely different programming languages.

Comment: Another solution would be to rewrite the Framework class library to be in Core?

Comment: So if I wanted to access a Core console app appsettings.json file from from the newly Core class library,  that code above should do it?  It doesn't seem to be finding it. Null Reference etc.  Or does it have to be done a different way?